# Postgres: select all row with count of a field greater than 1

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have table storing product price information, the table looks similar to, (no is the primary key)

```
no   name    price    date
1    paper   1.99     3-23
2    paper   2.99     5-25
3    paper   1.99     5-29
4    orange  4.56     4-23
5    apple   3.43     3-11
```

right now I want to select all the rows where the "name" field appeared more than once in the table. Basically, i want my query to return the first three rows.

I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM product_price_info GROUP BY name HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

but i get an error saying:

> column "product_price_info.no" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Answer (score 87, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM product_price_info 
WHERE name IN (SELECT name 
               FROM product_price_info 
               GROUP BY name HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Comment: Better (as in faster) to use e.g. `COUNT(id)` per the official docs.

Comment: You could join "name" inside the subquery with the group by, and use the "exists" clause instead of "in". I think it's faster

Comment: @Madbreaks, where exactly in documentation?

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```
SELECT no, name, price, "date"
FROM (
  SELECT no, name, price, "date",
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY name) AS cnt 
  FROM product_price_info ) AS t
WHERE t.cnt > 1
```

You can use the window version of `COUNT` to get the population of each `name` partition. Then, in an outer query, filter out `name` partitions having a population that is less than 2.

Comment: I have tested the versions from Juan Carlos Oropeza, Giorgos Betsos, and jarlh in SQLite3. This version is the fastest one. It's 26% faster than the other two.

Answer (score 11):

[Window Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/tutorial-window.html) are really nice for this.

```
SELECT p.*, count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY name) FROM product p;
```

For a full example:

```
CREATE TABLE product (no SERIAL, name text, price NUMERIC(8,2), date DATE);

INSERT INTO product(name, price, date) values
('paper', 1.99, '2017-03-23'),
('paper', 2.99, '2017-05-25'),
('paper', 1.99, '2017-05-29'),
('orange', 4.56, '2017-04-23'),
('apple', 3.43, '2017-03-11')
;

WITH report AS (
  SELECT p.*, count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY name) as count FROM product p
)
SELECT * FROM report WHERE count > 1;
```

Gives:

```
 no |  name  | price |    date    | count
----+--------+-------+------------+-------
  1 | paper  |  1.99 | 2017-03-23 |     3
  2 | paper  |  2.99 | 2017-05-25 |     3
  3 | paper  |  1.99 | 2017-05-29 |     3
(3 rows)
```

Comment: Nice but this doesn't fully answer op's question

Comment: @Madbreaks thanks for catching that. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Self join version, use a sub-query that returns the name's that appears more than once.

```
select t1.*
from tablename t1
join (select name from tablename group by name having count(*) > 1) t2
  on t1.name = t2.name
```

Basically the same as `IN`/`EXISTS` versions, but probably a bit faster.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT name, count(name)
FROM product_price_info
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(name) > 1
LIMIT 3
```

Comment: This doesn't do what the question asks for. It should select all columns for each row where the `name` value appears more than once. It should not add aggregation or new columns.

Comment: Funny enough this is the answer to the question I asked google and it gave me this SO